# jQuery Ajax Return HTML -- why can't i do stuff to it

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a form that get's processed via jQuery Ajax. Everything works well on the backend.
When the HTML comes back the script successfully performs the following: 
$("#msgMailingList").html(data);

However, I would like to hide the form if everything was processed correctly on the backend. I'm currently saying if what came back in HTML has a class formAction, then it should be ok. If what comes back has class called formErrors, do not hide the form.

Error via Firebug: 
"data.hasClass is not a function."

```
$(function(){
$("#formMailingList").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

    dataString = $("#formMailingList").serialize();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxMailingList.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {

      $("#msgMailingList").html(data);

      // the following doesn't work
      if (data.hasClass("formActions")) 
      {
         $("#formMailingList").hide();
      }

    }

    });          

});
});
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: try `data = $(data);` and then lunch jQuery methods on it 'coz atm it's just plain text or raw dom element(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should wrap that in a jQuery object  (this assumes that you are returning a simple html element like `<div class='formActions'>Everithing ok</div>`)

```
  // the following doesn't work
  if ($(data).hasClass("formActions") )
  {
     $("#formMailingList").hide();
  }
```